# Question about hyperbolic angle.

Tags: conic-sections, hyperbolic-functions

There is a generally very helpful website which says the following about the hyperbolic angle: "...hyperbolic trigonometric functions take area as their argument (called "the hyperbolic angle," but this is just a name and has nothing to do with angles)..."

From studying other sites it would seem that it has a lot to do with angles, in fact it is an angle which is also twice the area under a line from the origin to a point on the hyperbola, aka sector area. Just checking I understand correctly.

Comment: https://trigidentities.info/hyperbolic-trig-identities/

Comment: Side note: this is the reason why the inverse hyperbolic functions are actually called $\operatorname{arsinh}$ (and so on) rather than $\operatorname{arcsinh}$: Because they are for finding areas of the unit hyperbola, as opposed to the inverse trig functions, which find arc lengths of the unit circle. Not everyone spots that there is a difference in the first place, and hence the misnamed $\operatorname{arcsinh}$ is common enough, wrong though it is.

Comment: Sorry folks, it is correct to say there is no relation to the angle, as far as I can tell here: https://u.cubeupload.com/jbcooper/Unithyper.png (sorry, should have said arsinh ;-).